# Libre Office array of number 1 to n

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm looking for an array formula that returns me the number 1 to 5 as an array, similar to what for example the python function range(1,5) would do.

Input: {=range(1;5)}

Output: [image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Please try extension [**ListOK**](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/5118).

Your task can be solved with `=LSTVAL("1-5")`

[image: Example]

Or you can use different variations with the [**ROW()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060109.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3147321) function

[image: ExampleROW]

Comment: Im looking for a native implementation since i will be sharing the sheet. Is there a way to do that?